# Minimize the performance cost of reading a XML

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

My XML file is like..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Controls>
      <Control ToValidate="0" ControlID="cmbTrialType" ControlType="FormControl"   EngineValueID="" Enabled="0" Visible="1" Single="1" Input="1" Value="Superiority" ListInitValues="Superiority" FormulaEntered="" Caption="" IsValid="1" DecimalPlaces="" /> 
      <Control ToValidate="1" ControlID="cmbTrialType" ControlType="FormControl" EngineValueID="" Enabled="1" Visible="0" Single="1" Input="1" Value="Superiority" ListInitValues="Superiority" FormulaEntered="" Caption="" IsValid="1" DecimalPlaces="" /> 
</Controls>
```

I need to read this xml and perform following operation

1. If validate attribute is prsent check its value i.e. 0 or 1 and perform some action
2. If validate attribute is not prsent dnt do anything i.e. dont check its value.

I tried writing following function but its performance cost is much more.

```
public void LoadXML(String xmlFileName)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start(); 
            string refernceFileName = xmlFileName;
            XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(refernceFileName);
            //int count = 0;
            // Read until end of file
            while (textReader.Read())
            {
                XmlNodeType nType = textReader.NodeType;

                // if node type is an element
                if (nType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (textReader.Name.Equals("Control"))
                    {
                        if (textReader.AttributeCount >= 1)
                        {
                               String val = string.Empty;
                               val = textReader.GetAttribute("Visible");

                               if (!(val == null || val.Equals(string.Empty)))
                               {
                                   int choice = Int32.Parse(val);
                                   switch (choice)
                                   {
                                       case 0: Console.WriteLine("Visible");
                                           break;
                                       case 1: Console.WriteLine("Not Visible");
                                           break;
                                   }
                               }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", sw.Elapsed);
            //Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
```

Comment: Ok. So what have you tried so far?! We aren't here to do your homework.

Comment: That's nice. And what is your question? Did you encounter some specific problems when trying to achieve this task? Remember that StackOverflow is not an outsourcing company where you post your customer/boss/teacher requirements and receive source code in exchange.

Comment: I tried writing above function

Comment: Please clearly state your question. I'm guessing you need a function that executes more quickly (i.e. less of a performance cost)? If so (or not), edit your 'post' and add a real question.

Comment: “but its performance cost is much more” is not a question.

Comment: I know that StackOverflow is not an outsourcing company.All i was facing was a performance issue so i posted a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny,@Darin Dimitrov please answer

Comment: Speaking about performance, don't expect an answer when you haven't clarified your results, expectations, and goals. Your algorithm is pretty straightforward and O(n), so what's the problem? (Besides it won't validate the file's schema.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var elements = xml.Elements("Control").Where(
    e => e.Attribute("ToValidate") != null 
    && e.Attribute("ToValidate").Value == "1"
);
```

Comment: Being this the accepted answer I suppose the OP confuses performance and length of code :-)

Comment: I wonder why the last portion of my answer (copied) and marked as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

See this:

```
var xml = XElement.Load(@"path\to\your\xml\file");

var elements = xml.Elements("Control").Where(e => e.Attribute("ToValidate") != null);

foreach(var element in elements)
{
    var validateAttribute = element.Attribute("ToValidate").Value;
    if (validateAttribute == "0")
    {
        // something if invalid
    }
    else 
    {
        // something if valid
    }
}
```

If you have an intention just to work with elements where only `ToValidate="1"` or `ToValidate="0"` is present. You may consider using this:

```
var elements = xml.Elements("Control").Where(e => e.Attribute("ToValidate") != null && 
                                                  e.Attribute("ToValidate").Value == "1");
```

Answer (score 0):

1.leave as is perform checkval operation

1. create the control and do not validate it do not check its value

hope you pass the class